# Optional Where clause in query

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, objectquery

I have an application that does a search of our database (exposed via EF) for records meeting certain conditions. We have two main tables (Jobs and Recipients). Recipients are linked to the Jobs table by a Job ID.

The job record has various fields (Process Date, Name, JobType). The recipient has a lot of Name and ID fields (e.g. Account Number, Surname, etc)

I want to present a search screen where they see a list of fields to search on. The ASP.net code then sees which textboxes the user typed in (or selected), and builds a query based on that.

I'm just trying to find the most efficient way possible.

The rough logic is :

```
    if not string.isnullorempty(txtName.text) then
        'Query.Where.Add clause = " AND Name like '@txtName'
        'Query.WhereParameters.Add("@txtName",txtNAme.text
    end if

if not string.isnullorempty(txtAccountNumber.text) then 

.....etc


 if not string.isnullorempty(txtFromDate.text) then..
```

Where I'm stuck is figuring out how to add in additional where clauses. Should I just use Entity SQL?

Can this return strongly typed EF objects as well? And is it possible to return both the Jobs and Recipients objects?

e.g. if I did a select recipient.*, jobs.* from....blah would this parse correctly and return linked Recipient and Job objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start from a strongly-typed unfiltered query, you can add filters using `Queryable.Where`.

```
Name = txtName.Text
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) Then
    Query = Query.Where(Function(j) j.Name.Contains(Name))
End If
```

If your unfiltered query correctly links multiple records, those links will be preserved when you add a filter.

(Disclaimer: I don't usually use VB.NET; there may be silly syntax errors, but you should be able to get the general idea.)

Comment: So if I keep calling query.where and add in new functions, theyll be comined similar to an "and" in SQL? E.g name = john and date = @date. Is there a way to specify they be joined as an or?

Comment: 1) Yes. (Do remember the `Query = ` part, don't just call `Query.Where` and ignore the result.) Conceptually, `Query = Query.Where(a).Where(b).Where(c)` does (pseudo-code) `Query = (select * from (select * from (select * from Query where a) where b) where c)`, but that gives the same results as `Query = (select * from Query where a && b && c)`, and EF will usually translate it as such. 2) You could use `Union` for this. `Query.Where(a).Union(Query.Where(b))` gives the same results as `Query.Where(a || b)`.